# Which CommCareHQ Reports support locations/organizations?

Tags: commcare

I'm looking to find all the reports that support organizations. Does this information exist anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a table of the reports that support locations/organizations here: https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Viewing+Data+Assigned+to+Locations

Comment: There's also some information on which reports (and features) are restricted here: https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Location-Based+Data+Access+and+User+Editing+Restrictions